# Get overview of program structure by summarizing function calls

Tags: r, function

I have a set of global functions :

```
hw     <- function() print("hello world")
gbcw   <- function() cat("Good bye cruel world\n")
wu     <- function() print("what's up ?")   
hwgbcw <- function() {hw();wu();hwgbcw()}
```

We assume that all of these functions are defined in the global environment and never overloaded.
Let's put the functions that interest me in a vector (all but `wu`), along with `print` from base environment

```
my_functions <- c("hw","gbcw","hwgbcw","print")
```

What I would like is a summary of this form :

```
get_dependencies(my_functions)
#       f called_in
# 1    hw    hwgbcw
# 2  gbcw    hwgbcw
# 3 print        hw

get_dependencies(my_functions,recursive = TRUE)
#       f called_in
# 1    hw    hwgbcw
# 2  gbcw    hwgbcw
# 3 print    hwgbcw
# 4 print        hw
```

The goal is to :

- get easy overview my own programs
- check if there are some functions that I don't use anymore and just hang there polluting my code
- understand forgotten programs
- understand someone else's code
- Possibly build tree visualizations from these output tables

Is there a package does this kind of things ? If not, how would you go at it ?

Comment: have you tried [miniCRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-dependency-graph.html) ? May be helpful

Comment: I haven't but the visualizations look great many thanks, it seems that I could create a temporary package and execute `miniCRAN` on it

Comment: Maybe [CodeDepends](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CodeDepends/vignettes/intro.html)

Comment: Excellent, I'll take a look at this as well thanks.